# Rails 3 Routes and Namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have recently inherited an app where a user's edit account methods along with public account methods all live in the same controller. I am looking to try to make things a little more "Rails-esque" to clean the app up.

Here are the current routes

```
resources :user, :only => [:update, :show] do
    member do
      get :edit_account
      put :edit_account
      put :update_billing_information
      put :update_account_type
      get :edit_vitals
      get :edit_videos
      get :edit_athletic
      get :edit_academic
      get :edit_social
      get :edit_news
      get :edit_contributors
      get :edit_primary_sport_positions
      get :edit_primary_sport
      get :edit_primary_sport_highlights
      delete :remove_alternate_position
      get :vitals
      get :videos
      get :athletic
      get :academic
      get :social
      get :news
      post :keep
      post :draft
      get :share
      post :share
      get :notes
      post :notes
      get :contact
      post :contact
      post :cut
      delete :deactivate_account
      delete :delete_authorization
    end

    get :change_current_sport, on: :collection
  end
```

I reckon what I am looking for is, what would be the best rails best practices to move this towards routes that resemble `/user/edit/account` or `/user/edit/billing`?

Comment: If they're associations of the user use nested resources. IMO that's backwards from what you say you want, but it's also more RESTful.

Comment: @DaveNewton -- Can you give me an example? a user has_many videos if that helps

Comment: Implementing a RESTful app is more about how you organize your controllers and actions. This is a good presentation on the subject. Bear in mind it uses the old syntax for routes. http://www.slideshare.net/calamitas/restful-best-practices